# Netty: SimpleLeakAwareByteBuf: when does it arrive?

Tags: netty

In chapter 2 of the book "Netty In Action" Echo example

server side I get:

```
Server received: SimpleLeakAwareByteBuf(UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 12, cap: 1024))
```

but client side is OK

```
Client received: 4e6574747920726f636b7321.
```

Can anyone please explain why is `SimpleLeakAwareByteBuf` coming up instead of `4e6574747920726f636b7321`?

What does the message actually mean?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find answer on this question ?

Comment: Later I decided not to use Netty. Rather I used Java 7 NIO2  AsynchronousSocketChannel

Comment: why do u reject netty ? what reason?

Comment: Lack of resources for Netty. On the contrary core Java is much more reliable than 3rd party solution.